# Parse CSV based on random header layout perl

Tags: regex, perl, variables, csv

I am trying some code using Tie::Handle::CSV, however I suppose this could be done using other modules or none at all.

What I want to do is take a file of random layout and match it to what I predict the headers will be.  Then I want to arrange it to my table structure.

**DATA**

First Name,last name,date of birth
Jim,Johansen,08/25/1989

OR

2nd Name,1st Name,D.O.B
Johansen,Jim,08/25/1989

OR

2nd Name,1st Name,D.O.B,city,county
Johansen,Jim,08/25/1989,milwaukee,N/A

As you can see, I have varying data structures.  I want it to arrange them to my schema, even if the fields I request are empty.  The way I want to do this is by searching my input with my column variables.

Here is what I am trying.

**Code**

```
use Tie::Handle::CSV;
my $name1 =qr/First Name|Name|1st Name/i;
my $name2 =qr/Last Name|Maiden Name|2nd Name/i;
my $date_of_birth =qr/date of birth|D.O.B/i;
my $city =qr/city|town/i;
   my $csv_fh = Tie::Handle::CSV->new('list.txt', header => 1);
   while (my $csv_line = <$csv_fh>)
      {
      print $csv_line->{'$date_of_birth'}.",".$csv_line->{'$name1'}." ".$csv_line->{'$name2'}.",".$csv_line->{'$city'}.\n";  ##note I am searching for the column {$'colummn regex'} instead of {'column'} to see if my input file matches any of the header options.
      }
   close $csv_fh;
```

My output is blank since this module is not understanding the regex I am implimenting.  However, my output would contain the columns specified if I used their literal names, i.e.

The out put I want would be:

**Scenario 1**

Date of Birth,Name,City  ##my implemented header
08/25/1989,Jim Johansen,  ##noting also that if there is no 'city' in the input  data, leave blank.

**Scenario 2**

Date of Birth,Name,City  ##my implemented header
08/25/1989,Jim Johansen,

**Scenario 3**
Date of Birth,Name,City  ##my implemented header
08/25/1989,Jim Johansen,milwaukee

Perhaps there is a better option than a module or even my regex variables.  Has anyone had to parse csvs in ever changing layouts?

Comment: Most CSV parsers have options that include a header as the first record. That usually gives the amount of columns. You can always parse the records yourself and extract any column you like, based on the field data that you could examine with your regexes.

Comment: An alternative approach is to set up a relational database in which you retain the original data in separate tables and build up the inferred table with `SELECT` ... `UNION` queries (or `INSERT` ... `SELECT`).  That way you can always any mistakes in your inferences.  You could use [`DBD::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD::CSV) to read the tables and [`DBD::SQLite`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD::SQLite) to create the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never use `$name1`, `$name2`, etc, much less in a match (or substitution) operator, so you ever execute any regex match.

```
my $field_names = $csv_fh->header();

my ($name1_header) = grep /First Name|^Name$|1st Name/i,     @$field_names;
my ($name2_header) = grep /Last Name|Maiden Name|2nd Name/i, @$field_names;
my ($dob_header  ) = grep /date of birth|D\.O\.B/i,          @$field_names;
my ($city_header ) = grep /city|town/i,                      @$field_names;

my @recognized_fields = ( $name1_header, $name2_header, $dob_header, $city_header );
my %recognized_fields = map { $_ => 1 } @recognized_fields;
my @other_headers = grep !$recognized_fields{$_}, @$field_names;

while (my $row = <$csv_fh>) {
   my $name1 = $name1_header ? $row->{$name1_header} : undef;
   my $name2 = $name2_header ? $row->{$name2_header} : undef;
   my $dob   = $dob_header   ? $row->{$dob_header  } : undef;
   my $city  = $city_header  ? $row->{$city_header } : undef;

   my @other_fields = @$row{@other_headers};

   ...
}
```

Comment: what if there is no header to read or the header does not match the given layout, and I want to put those rows in a separate file? @ikegami